# Upgrading SSD Capacity - Clone Drive

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I currently have a 60GB SSD that I have as my OS drive for Windows 7 partition and Fedora17 partition.  Most data is stored on my 500GB hard disk.  I have upgraded to a 120GB drive, and want to clone the 60GB drive over to my 120 drive.  Right now my current layout is roughly 40GB for Windows 7 and 20 for Linux (GRUB - Windows -Linux).  What I am trying to figure out is if I were to clone that directly to the 120GB I would be left with something like (GRUB - 40GB Windows - 20 Linux - 60 Spare).  My Linux install is pretty simple, and won't need too much more space, most of the space I would like to dedicate to Windows.  Is having my extra space at the end (after my Linux partition) a problem?  Or does it not matter?

Or would I be better to remove my Linux partition, clone the existing data to the new drive, and set up my Linux partition on the last 20 GB or so of the 120 drive?

Comment: Clone the drive and simply enlarge the Windows partition afterwards. No need to remove anything. Modern partition tools move the data while resizing partitions automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several different clone utilities and none seemed to work well.  At first I had to reinstall Grub2 using 
`grub2-install /dev/sdXY` which worked to boot Linux but my Windows 7 installation had errors saying something similar to cannot find /H/S/C on hdX.

I tried using EaseUS Partition Manager and Acronis.  Neither worked.

Eventually I tried Clone Disk, which I don't remember the differences between the different software listed above and Clone Disk, but one starts the clone at a given sector, and the other at a given block. (I think).

Anyways, Clone Disk worked great.  No problems, didn't even have to reinstall grub2.

Answer (score 2):

The `gparted` CD makes it easy to move and resize partitions and most common file systems (including Linux ext2/3/4 & xfs, and Windows NTFS).

Suggested procedure is to clone the old SSD to the new one (e.g. with `dd`), then boot into a [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) CD, move the Linux partition to the end of the disk, then expand the NTFS partition).

`gparted` can be used to do the cloning as well as the resizing.

Another alternative is [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) which can also do disk cloning and partition resizing, but with a text-mode menu interface rather than a GUI.  IMO it is more capable and featureful than gparted (and comes in 64-bit versions as well as 32-bit which is useful if you need to chroot into a 64-bit Linux rootfs for rescue/repair operations), but can be harder to use.

It's certainly easier to do the disk cloning in Clonezilla, so you may want to use both - boot a Clonezilla CD for cloning and then boot into GParted for easy GUI resizing.